# Unity camera spinning around uncontrollably

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to clamp the camera rotation but when doing so the camera spins out uncontrollably. I tried it with `Math.fClamp` and another way and both seem to do the exact same thing.

Here is the code that I use:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float mRotY;

    private void Start () 
    {
        if (rigidbody) rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        Screen.lockCursor = !Debug.isDebugBuild;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate () 
    {  
        mRotY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * GameManager.sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (mRotY > 270.0f) mRotY = 270.0f;
        else if (mRotY < 90.0f) mRotY = 90.0f; 

        transform.Rotate(mRotY, 0.0f,0.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting `mRotY` to lower values for example [-10;+10]
Rotate method is relative to actual rotation so you don't want to rotate camera above 90 degrees every time.